# scrollable content into percentage sized div

Tags: html, css, scroll, percentage

I got a div container and a div content.
The content size has fixed height and width.
I would like the container to have relative size (percentage) but when I'm not using fixed pixels values the heigth seems to be 100% no matter what percentage I specify...

Html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 50%;  /* percentage value does not work */
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LePioo/2pcaq45x/55/

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if is this what you are trying to achieve, but you can use vh on the container and the scroll will appears and your div content will stay the size you ajust.

```
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 50vw; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using percentage height won't/doesn't work because the height attribute has nothing to measure the height against. If the div attributes were swapped and the container was 600px in height then the content div would inherit that height measurement, and if it's height was set to 50%, it would only go to 300px if you see what I mean... As is there's nothing in the container div except for a different div, and it has no parent to inherit from.

In short, you should use `vh` (vertical height) for dynamic height.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 50vh; 
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque mattis lacus dolor, ut pretium metus luctus volutpat. Nulla eleifend purus bibendum lectus posuere, non feugiat lorem porttitor. Aenean at sapien est. Vivamus urna massa, vestibulum at augue sit amet, vehicula fermentum justo. Mauris vulputate dictum sapien fermentum scelerisque. Vestibulum id augue feugiat, laoreet libero non, aliquam dolor. Vestibulum molestie, arcu a tincidunt maximus, ipsum urna euismod lectus, ac eleifend erat neque vitae nunc. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur non diam sed diam aliquam sodales sodales gravida lectus. Nunc elementum mauris a convallis dignissim. Phasellus augue tortor, tincidunt eget leo vitae, semper auctor est. Donec posuere diam ut venenatis laoreet. Sed ac metus eleifend, iaculis tortor vel, finibus nibh. Aliquam imperdiet, felis id tincidunt maximus, purus libero fermentum tellus, non suscipit ante magna a tortor. Sed finibus, risus nec laoreet ullamcorper, lectus ipsum consectetur magna, et condimentum neque quam non libero. Pellentesque bibendum, turpis eu lacinia varius, est massa placerat ante, vitae convallis purus orci volutpat tellus.
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Illustration of inherited /chopped height (overflow set to scroll so that you see boundaries)

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: scroll;
   width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.content {
  background-color: blue;
 height:50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque mattis lacus dolor, ut pretium metus luctus volutpat. Nulla eleifend purus bibendum lectus posuere, non feugiat lorem porttitor. Aenean at sapien est. Vivamus urna massa, vestibulum at augue sit amet, vehicula fermentum justo. Mauris vulputate dictum sapien fermentum scelerisque. Vestibulum id augue feugiat, laoreet libero non, aliquam dolor. Vestibulum molestie, arcu a tincidunt maximus, ipsum urna euismod lectus, ac eleifend erat neque vitae nunc. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur non diam sed diam aliquam sodales sodales gravida lectus. Nunc elementum mauris a convallis dignissim. Phasellus augue tortor, tincidunt eget leo vitae, semper auctor est. Donec posuere diam ut venenatis laoreet. Sed ac metus eleifend, iaculis tortor vel, finibus nibh. Aliquam imperdiet, felis id tincidunt maximus, purus libero fermentum tellus, non suscipit ante magna a tortor. Sed finibus, risus nec laoreet ullamcorper, lectus ipsum consectetur magna, et condimentum neque quam non libero. Pellentesque bibendum, turpis eu lacinia varius, est massa placerat ante, vitae convallis purus orci volutpat tellus.
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ooch.. never been a css lover but it looks like I've missed something huge with these vh and vw things!
I'll look into that, thanks

Comment: @LePioo did you accidentally un-accept? Came up as accepted for a sec?

Comment: sorry I accepted it too fast.. 
Looking into vh and vw I realised that's a solution for me and that my example is too simple for anyone to understand my real issue, I'm gonna edit it

Comment: @LePioo well you seem to have your css descriptors mixed up anyway.. and the container should be an id if you want content to inherit

Comment: what do you mean by "css descriptors mixed up" ?
I tried to change class to id but noting changed

Comment: @LePioo You seem to be confused about where to set the height, inheritance etc. Css seems to be incorrect for the purpose. Working on another question!